# Ошибки python 2.7: как сделать обработчик ошибок, чтобы программа не крашилась, а выдавала сообщение

Tags: python

Здравствуйте. Возник такой вопрос, как сделать обработчик ошибок, что бы например программа не крашилась, а выдавало соответствующее сообщение.
Пример: имеется программа, которая считывает данные с com порта и допустим если com port не верный, то программа выводит сообщение "Указан не верный com port", вместо непонятной ошибки в консоли. (python 2.7)

Пример кода:

```
try:
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port = 'COM1',\
        baudrate=2400,\
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=None)
 except SerialException:
    print u'неверный com port'
```

Comment: Смотрите какой исключение в вашем случае будет выбрасываться, ловите его в `except`

Comment: приведите явно в вопросе полное сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import traceback

def handle_exception(exception, value, trace):
    traceback.print_tb(trace, file=open('log.txt', 'a'))
    print exception, value, trace
    if exception is ZeroDivisionError:
        print True
    else:
        raise

sys.excepthook = handle_exception

1 / 0
```